# Equality of codimension under Lusztig-Spaltenstein induction

Tags: rt.representation-theory, nilpotent-orbits

Pardon if this is well known. Suppose I have a (say complex) connected reductive group $G^{\vee}$ with the $\tilde{\Delta}=\Delta\cup\{\alpha_0\}$ being the simple roots plus the negative highest root of $G^{\vee}$. Any proper subset of $\tilde{\Delta}$ defines a connected reductive subgroup $H^{\vee}\subset G^{\vee}$. Let $H$ and $G$ be the corresponding dual groups. For any special nilpotent orbit $u_H$ in $H$ we can define the Lusztig-Spaltenstein induction $u$ as a nilpotent orbit in $G$.

(that is, $(u_H,triv)$ corresponds to some representation of $W_H$ by Springer correspondence, we do the $j$-induction on this to get a representation of $W$, which correspond to $(u,triv)$ for some $u$)

> **Question:** Is it true that the codimension of $u$ in the nilpotent cone of $G$ is
>   the same is the codimension of $u_H$ in the nilpotent cone of $H$?

Thanks!

> **Edited:** Just to say what I understand / guess so far: For any $u_H$, say the Springer fiber $\mathcal{B}_{e_H}$ at $u_H$ has dimension $e_H$. Then the corresponding Weyl group representation appears as the component of $H^{2e_H}(\mathcal{B}_{e_H})$ on which $A_{e_H}$ acts trivially. This component receives a surjection from $H^{2e_H}(H/B_H)$, which is a quotient of $\text{Sym}^{2e_H}(std_H)$, where $std_H$ is the standard representation of $W_H$. The Lusztig-Spaltenstein $j$-induction then, I think (I cannot find a reference for why this works for $H^{2e_H}(H/B_H)$ instead of $\text{Sym}^{2e_H}(std_H)$), gives a $W$-representation in $H^{2e_H}(G/B)$, which then corresponds to some orbit in $G$ whose Springer fiber has dimension $e_H$.

Comment: I don't think you want to call the highest root $\rho$ (except in $SL_3$) because that's standardly used for half the sum of the positive roots.

Comment: Theorem 1.3(b) of Lusztig-Spaltenstein (Induced unipotent class) says the springer fiber of $u$ in $G$ has the same dimension as that of $u_H$ in $H$ if $H$ is a Levi of $G$. Is it going to help?

Comment: Definitely! I think their construction showed that the assertion is true when $H$ is a Levi (e.g. via the theorem you pointed out).

Comment: I learned from Prof. Lusztig that this is (essentially) true, and really follows from that in the definition of $j$-induction, the minimum number $e$ so that the interested rep'n of the Weyl group appears in $\mathrm{Sym}^e(std)$ is the same as the dimension for the Springer fiber. I'll try to add reference later when I read them better.

Comment: @Tsai: As Jay points out (and Lusztig suggests), there are relevant details in Lusztig's papers.   The extra groups $H$ are called "pseudo-Levi subgroups" by his former student Eric Sommers, though Eric and I disagree about whether that label should include the genuine Levi subgroups of parabolic subgroups.

Comment: Just corrected a mistake which I shamefully didn't understand until today. It's essential to have $H^{\vee}\subset G^{\vee}$ instead of $H\subset G$. For example, if $G=\mathrm{Sp}_4$, then the minimal orbit of $G$ will correspond to the non-trivial local system on the subregular orbit of $G^{\vee}\cong\mathrm{SO}_5$, which is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking for can be phrased entirely in terms of nilpotent orbits. If $\mathcal{O}$ is the nilpotent orbit of $H$ then the nilpotent orbit of $G$ you obtain via your process is the induced nilpotent orbit $\mathrm{Ind}_H^G(\mathcal{O})$. It is well known that the codimensions of these orbits coincide. See Proposition 7.1.4 of the book "Nilpotent Orbits in Semisimple Lie Algebras" by Collingwood and McGovern.

EDIT: Sorry, I just saw that you want this for a more general class of subgroups. The statement is still true. See 13.3 in Lusztig's book "Characters of reductive Groups over a finite field" and also Lusztig's paper "Unipotent classes and special Weyl group representations", J. Algebra (321), no. 11, 3418-3449, where more details are provided concerning some of the statements in the book.

Comment: Access online to the J. Algebra article is here: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869308001877